# Show multiple foreground service notifications with Android Studio

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, foreground-service

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc , to make an Android application with foreground notification service.
The problem is that the newer notif replaces the older, whereas i need the system to show both!
The source code is on https://github.com/Tunizoo/Skoola, i've followed the tutorial and added to it.

---

https://say-no-god-but-god.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

When you call NotificationManager.notify(id,notification) method to show the notification, pass a new id every time. If a notification with the given id is already shown, it will be replaced with the new one. So you need a new id to show the new notification and keep the old one as well.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it has not succeed. My source code is on https://github.com/Tunizoo/Skoola